# Vue JS, how to handle callback response from Social apps

Tags: github, vue.js

In Vue 2, I'm implementing Github Social Registration and login with my app.

In my Register.vue, I have button click that would lead to Github
`<button class="btn github" @click="registerWithGithub()"><i class="fab fa-github fa-fw"></i> Register with Github</button>`

`registerWithGithub()` method would look like this

`` registerWithGithub () {
      window.location.href = `https://github.com/login/oauth/authorize?scope=user:email&client_id=${this.githubClientId}`
    } ``

and I have configured a route to get callback from Github?

How do we manage those callbacks in Vue?

I have created a view component called `GithubCallback.vue` 
and my route would look like

```
{
  name: 'githubCallback',
  path: '/auth/github',
  component: GithubCallback
},
```

```html
<template>
  <div>callback</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'githubCallback',
  mounted() {
  }
}
</script>
```

However, clueless on how to handle callback response returned from Github.

Comment: `registerWithGithub()` where and what have you written in this function?

Comment: Where I redirect to github ```registerWithGithub ()  {
      window.location.href = https://github.com/login/oauth/authorize?scope=user:email&client_id=${this.githubClientId}
    }```

Answer (score 0):

Try [vue-authenticate](https://github.com/dgrubelic/vue-authenticate) plug-in. It helped me solve the same problem with Facebook